# reading a cookie to show a panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to read a cookie from the user computer, if this cookie existing , then i will show him a panel1 , if not , panel2 will be visible.

i guess this work will be done in the page_load code block , so here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (Request.Cookies["test"].Value)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

the problem is it highlighted `Request.Cookies["test"].Value` as an erorr , saying

> "Error> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'string' to 'bool'"

Any suggestions ?

using c# , visiual studio 2010 express, web forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Request.Cookies["test"]` may be null (if there is no cookie), so you need to test for that.

`Request.Cookies["test"].Value` returns a string, not a boolean. The `if` statement can only operate on boolean expressions.

You can use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) to check the value of the cookies - it will return true if there is no value or if it only contains whitespace and false otherwise:

```
if (Request.Cookies["test"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Cookies["test"].Value))
{
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    Panel2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but also it returned an error saying : 
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. , appreciate your help , thanks

Comment: @Bader - `Request.Cookies["test"]` will be a null object if the cookie is not set. You need to test for that too. Answer updated.